# In Xamarin ( UWP ) Pdfdtron Unable to delete pdf file

Tags: pdftron

Normally I am able to delete the pdf file, after viewing it by using PDFViewCntrl. But I am unable to delete the pdf file when I draw some annotaions on the pdf file using annotation tool.

I dispose tool manager, pdfviewCntrl and Pdfdoc, it works nicely for both ios and android. But the problem is only in UWP.

During the time of deletions it shows that "The process cannot access the file".

Comment: What version of PDFNet are you using? Please call PDFNet.GetVersion() at runtime.

Comment: Also, along with above question, can you reproduce using our samples, or only in your own project? What annotation are you adding? Have you tried running the latest version of UWP to see if that resolves the issue?

Comment: This version is 6.826. This problem arises only when any kind of annotations are added.

Comment: After some investigation, I found that, after drawing some annotations, when pdftron.PDF.Annots.Ink.Create(mPDFView.GetDoc().GetSDFDoc(), rect) (when freehand button is used) is called from Finish() function of pdftron code, file become locked, then it is impossible to delete the pdf file.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce using our PDFViewCtrl (or CompleteReader) sample project? Or this only occurs in your own project? Did you modify the Tools code for adding ink/freehand annotation? If so, can you post that change here.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? We would like to resolve this, but need the previous questions answered.

Comment: I cannot solve this issue, I didn't check your existing project to delete any pdf file after drawing some annotaions.

Comment: Knowing the answers to the questions I posted on the 15th are critical in knowing what the next step is. Otherwise, updating to the latest version (assuming you are not already) is a good next step.